What is the meaning of the coefficient of an interaction term for this particular regression?
If run the OLS regression (with an interaction term):
$$
y = c + \beta_1 x_{1} + \beta_2 x_{2} + \beta_3 x_{1} x_{2}
$$
What would the meaning of the $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ mean? Should the meanings of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ differ from the regression:
$$
y = c + \beta_1 x_{1} + \beta_2 x_{2}
$$
I am asking this question is because the value of $\beta_1$ changed alot from the second to the first regression.
I already understand that the meaning of $\beta_3$ is the increase in the value of $y$ for a unit increase in $x_{1}$ conditional on a unit increase in $x_{2}$ or vice versa (meaning the increase in the value of $y$ for a unit increase in $x_{2}$ conditional on a unit increase in $x_{1}$).

What is the subscript t for?  Also, while it isn't exactly wrong, this is not the standard way to write a regression. We would usually write $y = \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_1x_2$.  Finally, why not intercept term?

Hi @PeterFlom, thank you for your comments. I have edited my question to your recommendations, cheers.

This is a FAQ: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=interaction%20change&searchOn=3 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=interaction%20interpret*%20regression&searchOn=3.

When there is an interaction, the meaning of $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ is the expected change in Y per unit increase in the variable when the other variable is zero. That is, $\beta_1$ is the predicted change in $Y$ per unit increase in $X_1$ when $X_2 = 0$ (and similarly for $\beta_2$).

Hi Peter, thanks for your clear explanation. My variable $X_2$ is a continuous variable. Therefore, does that mean that the effect on $Y$ for a unit increase in $X_1$ is different for every value of $X_2$? ($X_2$ is bounded in the interval [0,1])

Yes, that is exactly what it means. Also, vice versa: The efffect on Y of a change in $X_2$ is different for every value of $X_1$

Let the regression model be:
$$
\mathbb{E}[y\mid x_1,x_2] = c + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + \beta_3x_1x_2
$$
If both $x_1$ and $x_2$ are absolutely continuous, then the expected marginal increase in $y$ with respect to an infinitesimal change in $x_1$, keeping $x_2$ constant, is a function of $x_2$:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\mathbb{E}[y\mid x_1,x_2] = \beta_1 + \beta_3x_2
$$
So, $\beta_1$ can be interpreted as the portion of the expected marginal increase in $y$, with respect to $x_1$, that does not vary with $x_2$. Notice that, if zero is in the support of $x_2$, we can say that $\beta_1$ is precisely the expected marginal increase in $y$ with respect to $x_1$ at $x_2=0$:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\mathbb{E}[y\mid x_1,x_2]\big\rvert_{x_2=0} = \beta_1
$$
